# Every separable metric space has cardinality less than or equal to the cardinality of the continuum

Tags: real-analysis, cardinals

I want to prove "Every separable metric space has cardinality less than or equal to the cardinality of the continuum".

$\textbf{I want to approach by sequences.}$

My attempt: Let $S$ be a countable dense subset of a metric space $X$. By density property  for each $x\in X$ there is a sequence $\{x_n\}$ in $S$ such that $x_n \rightarrow x$.

I want to define a injection from $X$ into $\mathbb{R}^S$. How can I?

If I can then we get easily that cardinality of $X$ is atmost that of continuum.

Please help.

Comment: $x \to (y\to d(x,y))$

Comment: @geetha290krm This includes metric. Can I  do it only using sequences?

Comment: @SuzuHirose I am looking for sequence approach. Your link uses metric approach.

Comment: @geetha290krm means, you are considering a map from $S$ into $\mathbb{R}$ via $y \mapsto d(x, y) $ where $x$ is fixed?

Comment: @user1234 See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2995939/a-first-countable-separable-hausdorff-space-has-at-most-the-continuum-cardinali