# Does a separable, $US$, sequential space have cardinality at most the continuum?

Tags: general-topology, cardinals, separation-axioms, separable-spaces

Let $X$ be a separable sequential space with unique sequential limits ($US$).  Can we prove that $X$ has cardinality at most $\mathfrak c=2^{\aleph_0}$?

##### Context.

If $X$ were Fréchet-Urysohn instead of merely sequential, we could apply the argument from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2995980/1210477).  As it stands, I would like to have a proof of the more general result for [$\pi$-base](https://topology.pi-base.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $D\subseteq X$ is a countable dense set.  For every ordinal $\alpha$, define the set the set $D_\alpha$ by transfinite recursion as follows:

$D_0=D$.

$D_{\alpha+1}$ is the sequential limit set of $D_{\alpha}$.

$D_{\alpha}=\bigcup_{\beta<\alpha}D_\beta$ when $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal.

If $|D_\alpha|\leq \mathfrak c=2^{\aleph_0}$, then since each $x\in D_{\alpha+1}$ is a limit of some sequence $(x_i)$ of points in $D_\alpha$, we have by $US$ that

$$\left|D_{\alpha+1}\right|\leq \left|D_\alpha^{\mathbb N}\right|\leq \left(2^{\aleph_0}\right)^{\aleph_0}=2^{\aleph_0}=\mathfrak c,$$

and if $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal, with $|D_\beta|\leq \mathfrak c$ for each $\beta<\alpha$, then  $$|D_\alpha|\leq |\alpha|\cdot \mathfrak c.\tag{1}$$

If $\alpha$ is also countable we then have $|D_\alpha|\leq \aleph_0 \cdot \mathfrak c=\mathfrak c$.

Thus by transfinite induction, $\left|D_\alpha\right|\leq \mathfrak c$ for each countable ordinal $\alpha$.

But then by (1), we also have $$|D_{\omega_1}|\leq \aleph_1\cdot \mathfrak c=\mathfrak c.$$

Moreover, we claim $D_{\omega_1}$ must be sequentially closed.  Indeed, if $x_i\to x$, and each $x_i\in D_{\omega_1}$, then each $x_i\in D_{\alpha_i}$ for some $\alpha_i<\omega_1$, so all the terms lie in $D_\alpha$ for $\alpha=\sup_{i\in\mathbb N}\alpha_i<\omega_1$, so we must have $x\in D_{\alpha+1}\subseteq D_{\omega_1}$.

Since $X$ is sequential, we have that $D_{\omega_1}$ is actually closed, so by density of $D$ we have $X=D_{\omega_1}$, whereby $|X|=|D_{\omega_1}|\leq \mathfrak c$.

Comment: What do you mean by $\alpha<\omega$ is a limit ordinal?

Comment: @StevenClontz oops that was supposed to be $\omega_1$, fixed now.

Comment: Proof looks good. With that change you can immediately say alpha.c = aleph0.c = c

Comment: Oh actually then I want to rephrase slightly - point was to use (1) a little lower down with $\aleph_1$, I'll fix, one sec. [fixed I think.]

Comment: Beautiful argument!  So that shows more generally: if $X$ is sequential and US and has a dense set of cardinality at most $\mathfrak c$, then $|X|\le\mathfrak c$.